# Indexes when left joining 2 tables with order by on second table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, left-join

This may be so easy for an experienced user, but I'm no able to fully understand what indexes are needed for this simple case.

I have a front-end table that can be sorted by any column besides some filters that can be applied for searching purposes:

```
id | username | email | name | phone | email_verified_at
```

The rows shown is a result of joining 2 tables (with a one-to-one relationship):

```
TABLE USERS

id | autoincrement
name | string
username | string | unique
email | string | unique
email_verified_at | timestamp | nullable

INDEXES
primary(id)
unique(name,id)
unique(username)
unique(email)
unique(email_verified_at,email)
```

```
TABLE PROFILES

id | autoincrement
user_id | FK(users)
phone | string

INDEXES
primary(id)
index(user_id)
unique(phone,user_id)
```

The most basic query, ordered by user id looks like

```
select
  `users`.`id` as `id`,
  `users`.`name` as `name`,
  `users`.`username` as `username`,
  `users`.`email` as `email`,
  `users`.`email_verified_at` as `email_verified_at`,
  `profiles`.`phone` as `phone`
from
  `users`
  left join `profiles` on `users`.`id` = `profiles`.`user_id`
order by
  `id` asc
limit
  11
```

Ordering by id, name, username, email, or email_verified_at performs a FULL INDEX SCAN in users table which I assume is correct.

[image]

But the trouble (or not) comes when I try to order by phone:

```
select
  `users`.`id` as `id`,
  `users`.`name` as `name`,
  `users`.`username` as `username`,
  `users`.`email` as `email`,
  `users`.`email_verified_at` as `email_verified_at`,
  `profiles`.`phone` as `phone`
from
  `users`
  left join `profiles` on `users`.`id` = `profiles`.`user_id`
order by
  `phone` asc
limit
  11
```

The first thing I see is that it's doing a FULL TABLE SCAN in users table.
In order to avoid that I need to create a UNIQUE index for users table containing:

```
id, username, email, name
```

Therefore the query performs a FULL INDEX SCAN over users table.
Despite that, I'm seeing that query cost is too high compared to sorting by users table fields.

[image]

Is that OK? Am I missing something here? I'm not sure if this is an expected result or it can be improved.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`profiles` needs an index *starting* with `user_id`.  The order of the columns in an index does matter.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`